# Amazon SES - Daily message quota exceeded automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, amazon-ses

I am using CodeIgniter to send emails like verification mail, forgot password mail etc. I tested 2-3 examples to check if the emails are going through. The tests were successful 12 hours ago. But now Amazon SES is showing that I have sent more than 50k emails in less than a day.

What should I do?

Comment: Well, did your application send 50k emails? Do you have logging in your application to check whether it is happening? Or, you can configure AWS CloudTrail to track what is happening. See: [Logging Amazon SES API Calls By Using AWS CloudTrail - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a bug or infinite loop in your code which caused your app to send way too many emails. Or a spam robot probably hit your website forms, and caused it to submit hundreds of password resets. This is common with prebuilt frameworks like CodeIgniter.

You should protect all your forms with a CAPTCHA so robots can't submit it.

Sidenote about Amazon SES: If you used an [independent email API like Flute Mail](https://www.flutemail.com/), you would be able to set it up with an automatic quota for SES, plus add alternate providers for when that quota was exceeded. And you would have access to the full email logs, so you can see exactly what your app has been sending (with the full contents of the email).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will surely set it up keeping everything in mind which you pointed out.